# How to change image.src in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have no idea how to change my code to change src content.
I used this command to do this but this solution won't work at all `image.src = textNode.img`.
Will you then be able to help me?
I have been struggling with it for a very long time, but it was all in vain.
It is very stressful when you cannot complete a very simple task.

```html
<!Doctype html>
<html lang="pl">
<head>
  <title>
    Anime
    </title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<style>
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="1.css">
  <script defer src="game.js"></script>
</head>
  <body>
<div class="scena">
<img src="unknown.jpg" id="myImage"><br>
<div class="przycisk">
    <div id="text">Text</div>
    <div id="option-buttons" class="btn-grid">
      <button class="btn">Option 1</button>
      <button class="btn">Option 2</button>
      <button class="btn">Option 3</button>
      <button class="btn">Option 4</button>
    </div>

</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
const textElement = document.getElementById('text')
const image = document.getElementById('myImage')
const optionButtonsElement = document.getElementById('option-buttons')

let state = {}

function startGame() {
  state = {}
  showTextNode(1)
}

function showTextNode(textNodeIndex) {
  const textNode = textNodes.find(textNode => textNode.id === textNodeIndex)
  image.src = textNode.img
  textElement.innerText = textNode.text
  while (optionButtonsElement.firstChild) {
    optionButtonsElement.removeChild(optionButtonsElement.firstChild)
  }

  textNode.options.forEach(option => {
    if (showOption(option)) {
      const button = document.createElement('button')
      button.innerText = option.text
      button.classList.add('btn')
      button.addEventListener('click', () => selectOption(option))
      optionButtonsElement.appendChild(button)
    }
  })
}

function showOption(option) {
  return option.requiredState == null || option.requiredState(state)
}

function selectOption(option) {
  const nextTextNodeId = option.nextText
  if (nextTextNodeId <= 0) {
    return startGame()
  }
  state = Object.assign(state, option.setState)
  showTextNode(nextTextNodeId)
}

const textNodes = [
  {
    id: 1,
    text: 'You wake up in a strange place and you see a jar of blue goo near you.',
    img: '1.jpg' ,
    options: [
      {
        text: 'Take the goo',
        setState: { blueGoo: true },
        nextText: 2
      },
      {
        text: 'Leave the goo',
        nextText: 2
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    text: 'You venture forth in search of answers to where you are when you come across a merchant.',
    options: [
      {
        text: 'Trade the goo for a sword',
        requiredState: (currentState) => currentState.blueGoo,
        setState: { blueGoo: false, sword: true },
        nextText: 3
      },
      {
        text: 'Trade the goo for a shield',
        requiredState: (currentState) => currentState.blueGoo,
        setState: { blueGoo: false, shield: true },
        nextText: 3
      },
      {
        text: 'Ignore the merchant',
        nextText: 3
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    text: 'After leaving the merchant you start to feel tired and stumble upon a small town next to a dangerous looking castle.',
    options: [
      {
        text: 'Explore the castle',
        nextText: 4
      },
      {
        text: 'Find a room to sleep at in the town',
        nextText: 5
      },
      {
        text: 'Find some hay in a stable to sleep in',
        nextText: 6
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    text: 'You are so tired that you fall asleep while exploring the castle and are killed by some terrible monster in your sleep.',
    options: [
      {
        text: 'Restart',
        nextText: -1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    text: 'Without any money to buy a room you break into the nearest inn and fall asleep. After a few hours of sleep the owner of the inn finds you and has the town guard lock you in a cell.',
    options: [
      {
        text: 'Restart',
        nextText: -1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    text: 'You wake up well rested and full of energy ready to explore the nearby castle.',
    options: [
      {
        text: 'Explore the castle',
        nextText: 7
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    text: 'While exploring the castle you come across a horrible monster in your path.',
    options: [
      {
        text: 'Try to run',
        nextText: 8
      },
      {
        text: 'Attack it with your sword',
        requiredState: (currentState) => currentState.sword,
        nextText: 9
      },
      {
        text: 'Hide behind your shield',
        requiredState: (currentState) => currentState.shield,
        nextText: 10
      },
      {
        text: 'Throw the blue goo at it',
        requiredState: (currentState) => currentState.blueGoo,
        nextText: 11
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    text: 'Your attempts to run are in vain and the monster easily catches.',
    options: [
      {
        text: 'Restart',
        nextText: -1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 9,
    text: 'You foolishly thought this monster could be slain with a single sword.',
    options: [
      {
        text: 'Restart',
        nextText: -1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 10,
    text: 'The monster laughed as you hid behind your shield and ate you.',
    options: [
      {
        text: 'Restart',
        nextText: -1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 11,
    text: 'You threw your jar of goo at the monster and it exploded. After the dust settled you saw the monster was destroyed. Seeing your victory you decide to claim this castle as your and live out the rest of your days there.',
    options: [
      {
        text: 'Congratulations. Play Again.',
        nextText: -1
      }
    ]
  }
]

startGame()
```

Comment: Please read how to create a [mre].

Comment: Could your image object `const image = document.getElementById('myImage')` be loaded sooner than the DOM processed, could you wrap it into event which gets fired only after HTML is ready ? When in doubt, add console.log everywhere, every variable to confirm they are what you expect. And shrink the example to smallest reproducer, even moon landing was not done in one step, but in multiple inremental steps. If it's frustrating to you finish simple steps, then do not skip them, scale down just to the code which switches the image and add code only after that works

Comment: Open the page with Chrome. Open the inspector tool with Ctrl +Shift + i. Please let us know what 's written on console pane because it will help us identify the problem rather than looking at the whole code.

Answer (score 0):

Well, because you have not added the image links `img:'url'` to the `textNodes` except for the first one.

Try this:

```js
const textElement = document.getElementById('text')
const image = document.getElementById('myImage')
const optionButtonsElement = document.getElementById('option-buttons')

let state = {}

function startGame() {
  state = {}
  showTextNode(1)
}

function showTextNode(textNodeIndex) {
  const textNode = textNodes.find(textNode => textNode.id === textNodeIndex)
  image.src = textNode.img
  textElement.innerText = textNode.text
  while (optionButtonsElement.firstChild) {
    optionButtonsElement.removeChild(optionButtonsElement.firstChild)
  }

  textNode.options.forEach(option => {
    if (showOption(option)) {
      const button = document.createElement('button')
      button.innerText = option.text
      button.classList.add('btn')
      button.addEventListener('click', () => selectOption(option))
      optionButtonsElement.appendChild(button)
    }
  })
}

function showOption(option) {
  return option.requiredState == null || option.requiredState(state)
}

function selectOption(option) {
  const nextTextNodeId = option.nextText
  if (nextTextNodeId <= 0) {
    return startGame()
  }
  state = Object.assign(state, option.setState)
  showTextNode(nextTextNodeId)
}

const textNodes = [
  {
    id: 1,
    text: 'You wake up in a strange place and you see a jar of blue goo near you.',
    img: 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5uTa.png' ,
    options: [
      {
        text: 'Take the goo',
        setState: { blueGoo: true },
        nextText: 2
      },
      {
        text: 'Leave the goo',
        nextText: 2
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    text: 'You venture forth in search of answers to where you are when you come across a merchant.',
    img: 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJmeJ.png' ,
    options: [
      {
        text: 'Trade the goo for a sword',
        requiredState: (currentState) => currentState.blueGoo,
        setState: { blueGoo: false, sword: true },
        nextText: 3
      },
      {
        text: 'Trade the goo for a shield',
        requiredState: (currentState) => currentState.blueGoo,
        setState: { blueGoo: false, shield: true },
        nextText: 3
      },
      {
        text: 'Ignore the merchant',
        nextText: 3
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    text: 'After leaving the merchant you start to feel tired and stumble upon a small town next to a dangerous looking castle.',
    img: 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lgtq.png' ,
    options: [
      {
        text: 'Explore the castle',
        nextText: 4
      },
      {
        text: 'Find a room to sleep at in the town',
        nextText: 5
      },
      {
        text: 'Find some hay in a stable to sleep in',
        nextText: 6
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    text: 'You are so tired that you fall asleep while exploring the castle and are killed by some terrible monster in your sleep.',
    img: 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lqkl0.png' ,
    options: [
      {
        text: 'Restart',
        nextText: -1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    text: 'Without any money to buy a room you break into the nearest inn and fall asleep. After a few hours of sleep the owner of the inn finds you and has the town guard lock you in a cell.',
    img: 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5DGx.png' ,
    options: [
      {
        text: 'Restart',
        nextText: -1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    text: 'You wake up well rested and full of energy ready to explore the nearby castle.',
    img: 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYxHm.png' ,
    options: [
      {
        text: 'Explore the castle',
        nextText: 7
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    text: 'While exploring the castle you come across a horrible monster in your path.',
    img: 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/5v2TX.png' ,
    options: [
      {
        text: 'Try to run',
        nextText: 8
      },
      {
        text: 'Attack it with your sword',
        requiredState: (currentState) => currentState.sword,
        nextText: 9
      },
      {
        text: 'Hide behind your shield',
        requiredState: (currentState) => currentState.shield,
        nextText: 10
      },
      {
        text: 'Throw the blue goo at it',
        requiredState: (currentState) => currentState.blueGoo,
        nextText: 11
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    text: 'Your attempts to run are in vain and the monster easily catches.',
    img: 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BGfi.png' ,
    options: [
      {
        text: 'Restart',
        nextText: -1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 9,
    text: 'You foolishly thought this monster could be slain with a single sword.',
    img: 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/in9g1.png' ,
    options: [
      {
        text: 'Restart',
        nextText: -1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 10,
    text: 'The monster laughed as you hid behind your shield and ate you.',
    img: 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0JHK.png' ,
    options: [
      {
        text: 'Restart',
        nextText: -1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 11,
    text: 'You threw your jar of goo at the monster and it exploded. After the dust settled you saw the monster was destroyed. Seeing your victory you decide to claim this castle as your and live out the rest of your days there.',
    img: 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lqkl0.png' ,
    options: [
      {
        text: 'Congratulations. Play Again.',
        nextText: -1
      }
    ]
  }
]

startGame()
```

```html
<!Doctype html>
<html lang="pl">
<head>
  <title>
    Anime
    </title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<style>
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="1.css">
  <script defer src="game.js"></script>
</head>
  <body>
<div class="scena">
<img src="unknown.jpg" id="myImage"><br>
<div class="przycisk">
    <div id="text">Text</div>
    <div id="option-buttons" class="btn-grid">
      <button class="btn">Option 1</button>
      <button class="btn">Option 2</button>
      <button class="btn">Option 3</button>
      <button class="btn">Option 4</button>
    </div>

</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```